# How to print the value within the method in testcase?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, testcase, junit-rule

I need to print the value within the method using the test case.
My code is:

```
public void testgetAllRatingElementsWeekNo() throws Exception
{
    String METHOD_NAME = "testgetAllRatingElementsWeekNo";
    log.entering(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);

    populateForTestMethodValues("1");
    populateWeekOfList();
    int allRatingElementsWeekNo = weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportForm.getAllRatingElementsWeekNo();
    System.out.println("allRatingElementsWeekNo :" + allRatingElementsWeekNo );
    assertEquals("testgetAllRatingElementsWeekNo is Not Greater than Zero: ", allRatingElementsWeekNo > 0, allRatingElementsWeekNo);

    log.exiting(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);
}
```

I need to print my value before throw a exception.

Comment: `assertEquals(String, boolean, int)` looks weird

Comment: Maybe you want `assertFalse("not greater than zero: "+allRatingElementsWeekNo, allRatingElementsWeekNo > 0 )`

Comment: ok i try and let you know the result..

Comment: @thilo, still throw the Assertion Failed Exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21380/discussion-between-indian-google-and-thilo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a try and finally block and in finally you can print the message. I don't know if this could be done any better way than this:

```
public void testgetAllRatingElementsWeekNo() throws Exception
{
try {
    String METHOD_NAME = "testgetAllRatingElementsWeekNo";
    log.entering(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);

    populateForTestMethodValues("1");
    populateWeekOfList();
    int allRatingElementsWeekNo = weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportForm.getAllRatingElementsWeekNo();
    System.out.println("allRatingElementsWeekNo :" + allRatingElementsWeekNo );
    assertEquals("testgetAllRatingElementsWeekNo is Not Greater than Zero: ", allRatingElementsWeekNo > 0, allRatingElementsWeekNo);
} finally {
    log.exiting(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);
}
}
```